# SelectionChanged and a FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am working on a windows universal app,I have a FlipView with 2 pages,each page contains 4 buttons,I want when I scroll from page1 I get page2,I tried this way:

```
<Page.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlipViewItemTemplate">
<Grid Background="Transparent">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlipViewItemTemplate1">
<Grid Background="Transparent">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources
```

I called this method from my flipView named flipView1:

```
private void flipView1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
   flipView1.ItemTemplate = Resources["FlipViewItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
   }
```

what I get is one page with 4 buttons without scroll,is there any method can I use to show a diferent page in scrolling

thanks for help

Comment: is this possible in universal apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

May be the solution it's to use a DataTemplateSelector

here is a sample : 
1) The class has to inherit from DataTemplateSelector
nanamespace ExploringOfficeRestAPI.Styles.DataTemplateSelectors
{
    public class FileFolderDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate FileTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate FolderTemplate { get; set; }
        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var viewModelPublic = item as OneDrivePublicFile;
            if (viewModelPublic != null)
            {
                if (viewModelPublic.IsFile())
                {
                    return FileTemplate;
                }

```
            return FolderTemplate;
        }          
        return FolderTemplate;

    }
}
```

}
2) Define your XAML DataTemplate : 
    
        
            
                
                
            
            
                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                               Height="150" Width="150"
                               SelectionHighlightColor="{StaticResource EORAForegroundBrush}"/>
            
                              Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            
                              Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,-20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

```
    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="{StaticResource EORAForegroundBrush}" 
                         Style="{StaticResource EORATextBlockStyle}" Width="auto" Height="50"  
                          Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,-20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

3) Define the selector in your XAMl :
  xmlns:selector="using:ExploringOfficeRestAPI.Styles.DataTemplateSelectors"

```
        <selector:FileFolderDataTemplateSelector 
                    x:Key="FileFolderDataTemplateSelector" 
                    FolderTemplate="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}"
                    FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}"/>
```

4) And last define the ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FileFolderDataTemplateSelector}" for your FlipView